# how does w3c canonicalization work for document subsets?

Tags: xml, w3c, xml-namespaces, libxml2, xmllint

I am unsure if "xmllint --c14n" works correctly regarding
namespaces. For the following input, my hand-made legacy
implementation of W3C Canonicalization pulls down the
namespace decl xmlns:xsi to the Dcoument-Tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<conxml xmlns="urn:conxml:xsd:container.nnn.002" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:conxml:xsd:container.nnn.002 container.nnn.002.xsd">
  <MsgPain001>
    <Document xmlns="urn:swift:xsd:$pain.001.002.02">
      <pain.001.001.02>
      </pain.001.001.02>
    </Document>
  </MsgPain001>
</conxml>
```

Actual result according to my legacy implementation:

```
...
    <Document xmlns="urn:swift:xsd:$pain.001.002.02" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
...
```

But xmllint --c14n does not do this, it reports

```
...
    <Document xmlns="urn:swift:xsd:$pain.001.002.02">
...
```

Can someone explain who is right according to the spec and
why?

see for details: http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#Example-DocSubsets

Comment: do you have any outstanding questions?  Please comment on my answer if you do.  Please click the bounty point icon to award the points to me if you are satisfied.  If you don't award the points I will not get them but you will be charged anyway for posting the question.  See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty

Comment: Sorry, I have not been online for a while. Yes, your comment was very helpful, but I still have no confirmation on our side.

Comment: Can I still reward the bounty to you?

Comment: The bounty got awarded, thank you.  What kind of confirmation are you looking for?  The "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" is unnecessary because the schemaLocation attribute is not included in the document subset.

Comment: You question (title) refers to document subsets. When you use 'document subsets', you might need Exclusive c14n. Just a remark..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the spec (Section 4.6):

> Unnecessary namespace declarations are not made in the canonical form.

The "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" namespace is not necessary to represent the document subset because the xsi:schemaLocation attribute is not included and the namespace is therefore "unnecessary".